# Import coefficients from a tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I really need your help for a google script project. I have a sheet with 2 tabs.
One with parameters and associated coefficients. (columns 1, 2 and 3)
--> TAB 1

I have another tab with other parameters (some parameters are in common) and associated coefficients --> TAB 2

I'd like to create a code that imports the coefficients from TAB 2 and places them next to the correct parameters on TAB 1.
In other words, I would like to compare them so place them right next to the coefficients already filled in and opposite the correct parameter in TAB 1.

My code may need to start with something like:

```
var identifiers = []
  var database = []
  Base.getRange('A11:L' + Base.getLastRow()).getValues().forEach(r => {
    let id = r[0].toString()
    if (r[7] != '') {
      ids.push(id)
      dataBase.push([r[7], r[8]])
    }
    if (r[9] != '') {
      ids.push(id)
      dataBase.push([r[9], r[10]])
    }
    if (r[11] != '') {
      ids.push(id)
      dataBase.push([r[11], r[12]])
    }
  })`
```

I need your help, thank you in advance

Comment: the simplified sheet is here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12zxuXmYpC8EGjKxiYH_LIqLQlEgPAZjNxwokvFTU294/edit?usp=sharing     TAB 1 is "CR-MR" and TAB2 is "Base"

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the simplified sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12zxuXmYpC8EGjKxiYH_LIqLQlEgPAZjNxwokvFTU294/edit?usp=sharing

The input are the A coefficient and the B coefficient in the first tab ("CR-MR") and those of the second tab ("Base"). The output must be a board (see picture) with the A coefficient and B coefficient of the first tab, and in the right the A coefficient and the B coefficient of the second tab.

[Board (output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDz7C.png)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! The StackOverflow guidelines recommend to insert the contents necessary to answer the question (code, pictures, …) into the answer; not only link to them, because links tend to resolve to 404 after some years.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).